# How can Javascript capture these values?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a webpage that has this in it:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/analytics?vmv=2#fi=v-FLp5ViIYS7s" class="yt-uix-tooltip" title="View stats"> 
    <span class="vm-video-metric video-view-count">
        <span> 
            <span class="vm-video-metric-icon"> 
                <img src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt=""> 
            </span> 
            <span class="vm-video-metric-value">
                1,644
            </span> 
        </span> 
    </span> 
    <span class="vm-video-metric video-likes-count"> 
        <span> 
            <span class="vm-video-metric-icon"> 
                <img src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt=""> 
            </span> 
            <span class="vm-video-metric-value">
                13
            </span> 
        </span> 
    </span> 
    <span class="vm-video-metric video-dislikes-count">
        <span> 
            <span class="vm-video-metric-icon"> 
                <img src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt=""> 
            </span> 
            <span class="vm-video-metric-value">
                3
            </span> 
        </span> 
    </span>
```

I would like to capture the three values encapsulated by the `<span class="vm-video-metric-value"></span>` tags.

In Javascript, this would normally be done using the id tag. But since there is no id tag, how can these values be captured?

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript frameworks like jQuery?

Comment: I don't have much experience with that, but I might resort to using that if necessary, or if it makes this easier.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `getElementsByClassName` method, like so.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("vm-video-metric-value");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in IE8, though. My answer does. If this isn't a concern to the asker, then that's fine, but just thought I'd point that out. +1 anyway :p

Answer (score 2):

```
var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("span.vm-video-metric-value"), l = qsa.length, i;
var vals = [];
for( i=0; i<l; i++)
    vals.push(parseInt(qsa[i].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''),10));
```

`vals` is now an array containing the numbers you wanted extracted. Requires a browser capable of querySelectorAll, which almost all are (IE7 and down are not).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, and you should! It's really simple to learn and it will take you a week tops to start using it:

```
$('span.vm-video-metric-value').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

"For each span with class vm-video-metric-value, print the text inside to the console."

Easy as pie!

Please give jQuery a shot, it's a great library.

Comment: Are you aware that this code executes a total of 200+ commands? Whereas mine and cheeken's takes all of twelve. This is why you SHOULDN'T use jQuery.

Comment: @Kolink: Can you elaborate? I'm not following how this runs 200+ commands.

Comment: @SergioTapia: More than likely, he's referring to jQuery's core code that has to wrap the DOM elements in a jQuery object and things of that nature, which adds to the number of commands being executed and arguably adds to the execution time. Also worth noting that Kolink has a dislike for anything jQuery as I've seen him condemn it in several answers this evening.

Comment: @WesleyJohnson: In that case, that's acceptable overhead. I prefer code readability, especially in something as trivial as this. Over saving my computer the 'work' of doing 200 commands.